# JDBC setQueryTimeout not working?

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm querying MSSQL 2008 server thourgh JAVA, using the JDBC driver.
I do something like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = ...;
...
stmt.setQueryTimeout(60);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

I see that when there's a load on the SQL server, the statement doesn't get cancelled even though the timeout has passed.

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The timing for setQueryTimeout is not precise at all
- The exception relies on the server acknowledging the cancel command

So, YMMV unfortunately...

References: (can't find anything better, sorry)

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/06bea9b9-78cb-4d1b-8c12-5f06ed991cac/
- http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-jdbc/1017/setQueryTimeout-not-work

Comment: If I can't really rely on it, it shouldn't be there in my opinion.. thanks for the answer!

Comment: What if the server is very loaded? We see many times on our server that it's very loaded on I/O for example

Comment: @duduamar: You have problems them with server setup, design, code or indexing. We have very high loads with no timouts (2.5 million new rows per minute + dozens of complex queries in the same minute)