# JDBC Microsoft SQL timeout not fired

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am using`sqljdbc4.jar` for connection from my application to SQL Server via wifi. The connection works fine and queries too, but sometimes the wifi falls and I need to react - try to reconnect and then inform the user about a connection fail.

The issue is, even when I set query timeout, the execution hangs in case of disconnection and no `SqlTimeoutException` is fired.

The connection (username and psw deleted):

```
SQLconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://%address%;user=%UserName%;password=%password%;database=%db_name%");

SQLSelectStatement = SQLconnection.createStatement();
SQLSelectStatement.setQueryTimeout(2);
```

Execution of query:

```
String sql = "%my query%";
ResultSet rs;
try {
    rs = SQLSelectStatement.executeQuery(sql);
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    ConnectSQL(); //try to connect again
    rs = SQLSelectStatement.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

If the method throws a `SQLException`, I'll inform the user and continue. But the exception is never thrown, even in the case of connection lost.

What can I do to resolve this? I tried setting lock-timeout and logintimeout in connection string based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), method `SQLconnection.setNetworkTimeout` fires error too (if I understand it right, it is not implemented in microsoft driver).

The last solution I can think of is to implement some kind of timeout on my own, which will stop the query thread after a certain time. But I don't wont to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Not all drivers support query timeout (sometimes because the server doesn't support it); have you checked if the driver actually supports it?

Comment: MS JDBC driver looks like it supports it (in other case, it wouldthrow exception when setting timeout), bud it seems I did understand it differently than MS developers. based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6058168/4809220), for timeout, it must have connection to server. So i cannot use it to detect network failure. Temporary solution is to start connection again before each query. This has default timeout of 15 seconds which I didn't manage to change, but it is much better than hanging whole app in case of network failure. We are working on rewriting the whole app to C++ :-P

Comment: @MarkRotteveel A gew days of rest helped me to start again :-) See my answer with working code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my googling and reading, `setQueryTimeout` is useful only for limitting of query execution time, not for detecting of connection error.

I have found [this great article](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/) describing timeouts in JDBC drivers. All I needed was to hit `socketTimeout` which is not supported in MS JDBC driver.

I switched to [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) and rewrited my code a bit. Now it works as I expected.

```
//initialize SQL connection
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Cls_log.LogError(ex);
    }

private void ConnectSQL() {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<ip_address>/<db_name>;instance=<SQLserver_name>;loginTimeout=5;socketTimeout=2";
        SQLconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, <userName>, <password>);
        SQLSelectStatement = SQLconnection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Cls_log.LogError(ex);
    }
}
```

Executing my query

```
String sql = "%my query%";
ResultSet rs;
try {
    rs = SQLSelectStatement.executeQuery(sql);
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    ConnectSQL(); //try to connect again
    rs = SQLSelectStatement.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

If this throws SQLException, I inform user and offer workaround.

Comment: Good find. JTDS is in most cases superior to MS's driver.

Comment: Just FYI, socketTimeout is in seconds. Don't know why the example above is set to a 2 second timeout as the socketTimeout needs to be greater than the query's execution time according to the documentation

Comment: This helped us solve a recurring non-deterministic production issue which always warranted a restart of the application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, recent Microsoft driver supports it as well: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/85/files

Comment: Note that the "SocketTimeout" in the Microsoft JDBC driver is in milliseconds, not seconds!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=azuresqldb-current